# Net::HTTP::Post.new request returns empty body in Ruby 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In Ruby 2.0.0p195, Rails 4.0.0, Net::HTTP::Post.new request returns empty body of response.

```
    @toSend = {
        "zuppler_store_id" => 'X3r82l89',
        "user_id" => '1'
    }.to_json

    uri = URI("http://smoothpay.com/zuppler/gen_token_post.php")
    http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host,uri.port)

    req = Net::HTTP::Post.new uri
    req.content_type = "application/json"   
    req.body = @toSend   # or "[ #{@toSend} ]" ?

    res = Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port) {|http| http.request(req)}

    puts "Response #{res.code} - #{res.message}: #{res.body}"
```

This code returns "**Response 200 - OK:**"

But it should return like this: **{"result":"success","token":"843e5be88fb8cee7d324244929177b4e"}**

You can check it by typing this url:
http://smoothpay.com/zuppler/gen_token_test.php

Why is res.body empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like that service doesn't like the POST request to be `application/json`.

This works:

```
uri = URI("http://smoothpay.com/zuppler/gen_token_post.php")
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host,uri.port)

req = Net::HTTP::Post.new uri
req.body = "zuppler_store_id=X3r82l89&user_id=1"

res = Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port) {|http| http.request(req)}

res.body # => "{\"result\":\"success\",\"token\":\"9502e49d454ab7b7dd2699a26f742cda\"}"
```

In other words, give the service `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Peculiarly, it will hand  you back `text/html` which you'll have to `JSON.parse`. Weird service.